# How to Buffer with Dissolve ALL on very large polyline dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer, performance, large-datasets

So I have a fairly large polyline network covering a decent chunk of North America, containing just shy of 900,000 table records. I want to do some very simple "GIS 101" kind of processing to it -- I want to buffer everything with the "Dissolve" parameter set to "ALL".

Well, unsurprisingly, this is way more than ArcGIS is ready to take on, even w/ 6 GB RAM & with everything in a geodatabase. I know the "Dissolve" operation is more prone to running out of memory in such cases than "Buffer", so I tried to run "Buffer" without "Dissolve = ALL", but even that will not generate a usable output (the file exists but won't draw or reveal its attribute table). And, in any case, I am sure the subsequent "Dissolve" would hang.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Breaking up the network into smaller pieces. Well, this seems like a non-starter, because I need to make sure I don't cut any line segments apart in doing so. Of course selecting polyline segments sequentially from the attribute table
   will just select random pieces of polylines all over the place, shredding the integrity of the network.  I'm not sure how to break it up programmatically such that no connected pieces are broken apart.
2. Running the buffer & dissolve in QGIS, based on some hearsay that it was better at handling large datasets. Like ArcGIS, it also just hung there forever.
3. Importing everything into R with the "maptools" package and seeing if I could do it there. The data is so huge I couldn't even read it in within a reasonable time span.

There's a whole lot of talk out there about this kind of situation, but it always ultimately ends with "you need to find a way to break up your large dataset." I'm not really sure how this can be done cleanly with a huge network of stream polylines, barring some crazy Python script that can tell, for each polyline segment, which ones it's connected to, and select those only, until the entire spatially discrete sub-network is selected, write that to a single feature, & then move on to the next such sub-network.

This seems absurdly complex as a workaround for very simple processing on a not-even-all-that-big dataset (though I'll try it if I have to), but can anyone tell me how I can get this thing buffered?? Other software / workarounds / magic incantations / human sacrifice?? (And there'll be yet more steps after the buffer/dissolve, which would be no sweat with smaller data but will probably cause a minor earthquake if I try them with this beast).

**EDIT :**

After exploring this much more in-depth, I feel this question hasn't been adequately addressed by the duplicate question or the main suggestions here. Here's why:

1. The Dice tool appears to be for reducing the number of vertices in individual features? I don't have individual streamlines with >3,000 vertices, but in any case, I've used Dice with a vertices limit of 100, and still cannot run the dissolve.
2. Breaking the streams into 100 pieces and dissolving each one requires an "uber-Dissolve" at the end to combine the pieces, which will have buffers overlapping with one another. This "uber-Dissolve" experiences the same memory failure as the original approach, even though there is much less to dissolve after the 100 pieces have been processed. So this approach indeed doesn't seem to work, though for a completely different reason than what I stated earlier.

It seems PostGIS has implemented an approach called "cascaded unions" that addresses this general problem, which will be fun to explore, but in the meantime I was hoping for an ArcGIS-/Python-/QGIS-based solution.

Comment: The problem is that the temporary shapefile created has a maximum file size of 4GB (.shp and .dbf), you are probably exceeding that. Break it down into chunks by OID, buffer without dissolve, merge into a fGDB feature class and then dissolve in ArcMap edit session.

Comment: BTW. ArcGis is still a 32bit application, it doesn't care how much RAM you have it can only access 4GB. I am using an i7-4820k @ up to 3.9GHz with 32GB of memory and Adaptec RAID using Western Digital Red drives and there is no minor earthquake when I run up to 16 concurrent processes... the power of batch files! Please don't sacrifice anybody important for ESRIs' shortcomings.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that breaking it up is a non-starter?  If you break the dataset up into pieces based on attributes, i.e. Local roads, Major roads, Highways, etc.  Can you not buffer these and then merge them?

Comment: Is your data in an enterprise geodatabase? Maybe this could be accomplished more efficiently through SQL.

Comment: For other ideas see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer+performance

Comment: Well, the dissolve tool documentation makes specific mention of almost the exact problem you state and it suggests "For extremely large features created by the Dissolve tool, the Dice tool may have to be used to split the large features in order to solve processing, display, or performance problems."    Dice tool documentation is at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000037000000

Comment: The 'Dice' tool is an excellent option for this and other geoprocessing operations. Some tools are internally 'Dicing' like 'Integrate' to improve performance. Situations like this makes me wonder why shapefiles are still used by ArcGis as temporary when fGDB has no realistic size limit and why tools can't work out their own internal dicing regardless of how many input features.